# MySQL Server - Unable to login MySQL

Tags: server, apache2, login, mysql

I want to run MySQL commands from terminal. But getting the following error.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

On 1st time I change my `root@localhost` password and created another user `hello@ localhost` with all privileges. But after that couldn't login again. I used `mysql -h` during 1st setup.

These commands are causing the above error.

```
sudo mysql -u root;
sudo mysql -u hello;
sudo mysql -h localhost mysql;
sudo mysql -h localhost hello;
```

Note that I know my current passwords and want to change them.

Comment: why do you put a ; behind these commands? Please do not do that. Also: drop the sudo; not needed for a normal connecting to mysql.And "using password: NO"  claims you did not use a password. 
"I want to run MySQL commands from terminal"  you do that with the "-e"  option.

Comment: I do it because I'm use to it. I have a password, because in PHP if I don't enter a password, script doesn't work.